# Chromatic Polynomials of Circulant Graph With Two Parameters

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings, algebraic-graph-theory, circulant-matrices, chromatic-polynomial

I have been working with the chromatic polynomials of *circulant graphs of prime order* $p$ with two distinct parameters, i.e.

$P_{p,i,j}(x):= P(C_{p}(i,j),x)$ with $1 \leq i \neq j \leq \ n/2.$

In this regard, I have a couple of questions. Let $p$ be a prime number as above, and $1 \leq i' \neq j' \leq \ n/2$ and $1 \leq i \neq j \leq \ n/2$.  Are the following conjectural identities true?

1. $P_{p,i,j}(x) \stackrel{?}{=} P_{p,i',j'}(x)$; (No. Counter example by Jeremy Martin: $C_{11}(1,2)$  and $C_{11}(1,3)$)
2. $P_{p,i,j}(p) \stackrel{?}{\leq} e^2 * p^p$.

These questions seem to answer in positive in experiments, but I have not found literature that helps me to prove (or disprove) these statements. Any literature suggestions or ideas on how to approach them would be very helpful.

Best regards

Comment: Dear Abraham, is there any question you want to formulate in regards to your findings? I'd say a number of clearly stated questions would help enormously.

Comment: Yes indeed Sasha; It would be very helpful if someone can direct me to some literature or if someone would like to discuss some ideas on how to prove (or disprove) the experiment-based observations I did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that $C_p(i,j)$ means the graph with vertices $0,\dots,p-1$ and edges between each pair of vertices with difference $i$ or $j$ mod $p$.  If that is the case, then identity 1 does not appear to be true in general; Sage gives different chromatic polynomials for $C_{11}(1,2)$ and $C_{11}(1,3)$.  (By the way, you may as well assume $i=1$, because $C_p(i,j)\cong C_p(1,j/i)$, with the quotient taken in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.)